# Multi-projects Maven compilation issue

Tags: maven

I'm experiencing trouble trying to build a maven project with a multi-modules project.

In the main pom I have the following modules :

```
<modules>
    <module>moduleA</module>
    <module>moduleB</module>
    <module>moduleC</module>
</modules>
```

When it comes to build the third module (that includes the two others) where I'd like to generate a wsdl with a java2ws goal I get a ClassNotFoundException error (trace below)
I guess it occurs because the class is contained into a package from the moduleA. How can I specify in the java2ws command that the class is contained in another module ?

...

```
<execution>     
    <id>process-classes-reclamacion</id>
    <phase>process-classes</phase>
    <configuration>
        <className>com.classX</className>
        <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
            <goal>java2ws</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

...

```
GRAVE: Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:2.2.6:java2ws on project moduleC: Fail to load class : com.classX -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-java2ws-plugin:2.2.6:java2ws on project moduleC : Fail to load class : com.classX
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:134)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:69)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fail to load class : com.calculo.gestconv.webservices.reclamacion.sdm.IReclamacionSDMWS
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.Java2WSMojo.processJavaClass(Java2WSMojo.java:268)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.Java2WSMojo.execute(Java2WSMojo.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Fail to load class : com.classX
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.util.AnnotationUtil.loadClass(AnnotationUtil.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.processor.JavaToWSDLProcessor.getServiceClass(JavaToWSDLProcessor.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.processor.JavaToWSDLProcessor.getServiceBuilder(JavaToWSDLProcessor.java:204)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.processor.JavaToWSDLProcessor.process(JavaToWSDLProcessor.java:127)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.processWSDL(JavaToWSContainer.java:109)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.execute(JavaToWSContainer.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:58)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:40)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.run(JavaToWS.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.Java2WSMojo.processJavaClass(Java2WSMojo.java:265)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.classX
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.util.AnnotationUtil.loadClass(AnnotationUtil.java:80)
    ... 44 more
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: the command should not require the source code, it runs against the class file (not source file).  Are you sure it's on the classpath?  Please provide relevant sections of your pom.xml

Comment: Thank you John. The classpath tag was missing.

Comment: Hi John Ament, how can I set child modules as classpath in parent pom?